# Problem oauth Google Login in Identity server 3 MVC

Tags: owin, owin-middleware

im currently working on incoroporate Google Login on Identity Server 3. Im using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google but im struggling on what button do i have to put on my html to use google login. My code in my StartupClass is the following:`

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseAddress"];
            var identityAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["identityAddress"];
            var logoutUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["postLogoutRedirect"];
            var company = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationCompany"];

            app.Map(
                "/identity",

                coreApp =>
                {
                    
                    coreApp.Use(async (context, next) =>
                    {
                        var language = context.Request.Query[_languageKey];
                        if (language != null)
                        {
                            context.Response.Cookies.Append(_languageKey, language);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            language = context.Request.Cookies[_languageKey];
                        }

                        if (_cultureNames.Contains(language))
                        {
                            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(language);
                            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
                        }

                        await next();
                    });

                    coreApp.UseIdentityServer(
                        new IdentityServerOptions
                        {
                            SiteName = company,
                            SigningCertificate = Cert.Load(),
                            Factory = IdentityServerFactoryConfig.BuildIdentityServerFactory(),
                            RequireSsl = true,
                            AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions()
                            {
                                EnableLocalLogin = true,
                                IdentityProviders = ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders,
                                EnableSignOutPrompt = false,
                                EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
                                PostSignOutAutoRedirectDelay = 0
                            },
                            ProtocolLogoutUrls = new List<string>()
                            {
                                logoutUrl
                            },
                            DiscoveryOptions = new DiscoveryOptions
                            {
                                ShowIdentityScopes = false,
                                ShowResourceScopes = false,
                                ShowClaims = false
                            },
                            EnableWelcomePage = false,
                            CspOptions = new CspOptions
                            {
                                FontSrc = identityAddress + " " + baseAddress,
                                StyleSrc = identityAddress + " " + baseAddress,
                                ScriptSrc = identityAddress + " " + baseAddress
                            }
                        });
                

                   
                  
                });
        }

        private static void ConfigureAdditionalIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
        {
            var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Google",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                ClientId = "clientId(its okay in my code)",
                ClientSecret = "clientSecret(its okay in my code)",
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/oauth-redirect"),
                Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                    {
                        var email = context.Identity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
                        context.Response.Redirect($"http://localhost:7000/#/register-oauth?email={Uri.EscapeDataString(email)}");
                        //context.HandleResponse(); 
                    }
                }
            };
            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
        }
```

`
My idserver is running on localhost:44300. As you can see, the callback url is mapped on localhost:44300/identity/oauth-redirect, and this url is already in the google dev console.
I have put this button on my html:

Google login

(i have put "identity/external" bcs the app maps from the begining in the url "identity")when i click, im getting the following error:
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44300/identity/external?provider=Google'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Authentication' that matches the request."}

The idea after login is redirect to a component taking the user email.
Im pretty lost on this error, what shoul i do?